# Is there a way to Optimizing Linear Memory Model in WebAssembly for Improved Memory Management?

Tags: memory, memory-management, out-of-memory, buffer, webassembly

We've been exploring challenges the flat memory model in WebAssembly, as highlighted in Empowering Web Applications with WebAssembly: Are We There Yet?: https://weihang-wang.github.io/papers/wasm-ase21nier.pdf. The paper suggests WebAssembly have drawaback in managing memory effectively, particularly in larger programs.

Our aim is to conduct research to optimize the linear memory model in WebAssembly. However, we're uncertain about the possibility and potential directions for this research.

We didn't find much detailed literature around this memory model.

What we've done:
We're newcomers to WebAssembly and started by running an existing program in the environment. Our understanding of memory concepts in WebAssembly remains basic.

Our questions :

1. Has anyone explored similar research or attempted optimizations in this area?
2. Are there possible to modify memory models in WebAssembly that could potentially address the limitations mentioned in the paper?
3. What possibility methods and what's output possibility for this research?
4. What concern to use linear model than others model?

Comment: A common thing to do is looking at papers that cite the paper you are interested in: https://scholar.google.com/scholar?cites=14892051831301031088&as_sdt=5,39&sciodt=7,39&hl=en It seems to me, at a glance, that there are really few papers about the linear memory model and its limitations. I hope maybe some of the papers there help you, and look forward to your research on the topic.

Answer (score 0):

As a quick comment: the "linear memory model" is essentially what regular "native" processes running on today's computers use. From the point of view of any regular C/C++/Rust/... program, memory is a linear range of addresses, and the compiled program includes some form of allocator that decides which address to use next time the program allocates memory, and to this end keeps track of which addresses it has already used, and which have been freed.

A small difference for WebAssembly is that WebAssembly programs aren't native processes; instead the WebAssembly runtime (a.k.a. "engine") allocates a large array and uses that as the memory for the WebAssembly program. So there's a layer of encapsulation, but what happens inside the array that serves as WebAssembly memory is practically the same as what happens in each process' memory.

So I don't think there's much to discuss or research about the "linear memory model" itself. That said, there are many different allocator implementations, and the choice of allocator can have a big impact on both program performance and memory efficiency. Better allocators, and better choices of the right allocator for the right use case, are areas of ongoing research. If a WebAssembly program wants to use a different allocator, that is a choice that it can make entirely on its own; the allocator is not a property of WebAssembly itself.

---

There is one alternative approach that's fundamentally different, and that is "managed memory" (a.k.a. "garbage-collected memory") as used by languages like Java, Python, JavaScript and many others, where the respective virtual machine (which itself runs in linear memory provided by the actual machine) provides managed memory to the running application. To support such languages, WebAssembly has recently gained [garbage collection support](https://github.com/WebAssembly/gc/blob/main/proposals/gc/MVP.md). While both approaches have pros and cons, it is generally either outright impossible or a pretty bad idea for efficiency to compile programs written in a given language to an execution environment using the wrong memory model for that language. For example, trying to compile C++ programs to garbage-collected memory might sort-of work for very simple cases, but will make it impossible to support the full C++ language; similarly trying to compile Java programs to linear memory might be technically possible with a bunch of restrictions (there used to be a ["gcj"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Compiler_for_Java) project that did this), but hasn't caught on as a widely adopted technique due to its drawbacks.

---

The specific paper you quoted is pretty questionable. For example, it claims:

> most of the WebAssembly programs have performance
> improvement ratios close to one, suggesting that there is no
> substantial difference in performance with and without JIT.

Firstly, they tested with V8, and V8 has *no way at all* to execute WebAssembly without JIT. Apparently they confused the baseline JIT compiler for "no JIT".
Secondly, I happen to work on V8's WebAssembly engine full-time these days, and I can tell you with certainty that there is a *massive* performance difference between baseline-compiled code and optimized code. I don't know what went wrong with the measurements quoted in that paper, but at any rate, the conclusion they arrive at is bogus.

Possibly some of this is due to the paper being outdated. Apparently they've been testing a V8 version from late 2019, and V8's WebAssembly engine (like other WebAssembly engines in widespread use) has been under very active development in the 4+ years since then.

Also, it looks like they only considered one particular toolchain for producing WebAssembly modules. The choice of toolchain, and the optimizations it applies, have a huge impact on performance and memory efficiency of WebAssembly programs. Like engines, there are large differences between different toolchains; and also like engines, toolchains are under active development.